# How to punctuate interrupted dialogue

Tags: dashes, dialogue, em-dashes

What is the best way to punctuate interrupted dialogue? I have seen it done like this, but I am not sure if it is correct.

"In my opinion the best w--"

"Nobody is interested in your opinion," Fred cut in.

I think that this is called an em dash and that some softwares will put the two hyphens together to make a single, long em dash.

If this is the proper way to signify interrupted speech, is it OK if the software does not join the hyphens into a single em dash. Are two hyphens OK?

Comment: Sure, you do the best you can. If you can find the em dash anywhere, copy & paste it in. If you use MS Word, I can share other tricks.

Comment: software never takes an s.

Comment: In MS Word, type four characters: p - - p. When you type a space next, Word turns the hyphens into one em dash. Backspace twice to remove 'p space'. I use the letter 'p' only for its nearness to the Backspace key that I'll need.

Comment: Please stop worrying - stop even thinking about which dash to use where. Any such question is always and exclusively a matter of style.

If you're writing for a given journal, ask your editor for the house style.

If not, use whatever suits you best but please, don't think there's any *proper* or *best* or *preferred* style…